# How to prevent visitor from seeing app before redirection?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I am building a SPA using Vue-CLI with a client-side OAuth 2.0 javascript library called [JSO](https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso). It uses HTML 5.0 localStorage to cache Access Tokens.

**In my full app, I have everything functioning properly with the exception of the following issue:**

When the user arrives at my app for the first time, he catches a quick glimpse of the app and then automatically is redirected to a third party authentication login screen. I don't want that **"quick glimpse"** to happen -- I need to have the user immediately redirected to the third party login page BEFORE he sees any part of my app.

So, I thought I'd set up *[Global Before Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)* using Vue-Router like so:

> From: Main.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },

    ...more routes...and they all require auth...
]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem('my-token-example')
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    if (token == null) {
      client.getToken()
      next(false)
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

new Vue({
  created: function() {
    //check for response parameters if user has an auth token (uses JSO plugin)
    //if token received, then it is stashed into localStorage
    client.callback()
  },
  render: h => h(App),
  router: router
}).$mount('#app')
```

> Example App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
     <Header />
    <routerView />
   </div>
</template>
```

> Info on `client.callback()`:

I catch the headers response when user is returning to app

> Info on `client.getToken()`:

I get the token payload

Notes: The JSO auth docs state:
"You may also ensure that a token is available early in your application, to force all user interaction and redirection to happen before your application is fully loaded. To do that make a call to getToken, and wait for the callback before you continue.

REMEMBER to ALWAYS call the callback() function to process the response from the OAuth server, before you use getToken(), if not you will end up in an redirect_loop"

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can prevent the user from seeing my app before he is redirected to the auth login site? Update: I think I see the problem...is the global guards only affecting the section of the app within the `<RouterView />` component? Hence, we see the header and banner of my app before redirection?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this. I had to simply do a `v-if` on my `app.vue` file like: `<div v-if="token !== null>`

That hides the app template until token is received.